# Same Application bar for different xaml pages Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

For WP8 application, I have to create same application bar for different pages, do I need to create it in Xaml for all the pages or there is any way to define it once and use it across..

Answer (score 1):

you can define your appbar in App.xaml like this..

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneApp12" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="GlobalAppBar" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" BackgroundColor="Black" ForegroundColor="White">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="asd" IconUri="/1.png" Text="0"  />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/1.png" Text="1" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/1.png" Text="2"  />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/1.png" Text="3"  />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</Application.Resources>
```

and on your xaml pages add this.

```
ApplicationBar = "{StaticResource GlobalAppBar}"
```

so your page.xaml top part look like this..

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="PhoneApp12.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
 **ApplicationBar = "{StaticResource GlobalAppBar}"**
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
```

hope it help you..